# every flask form will generate a new CSRF token with CSRFProtection?

Tags: flask, csrf-protection

I am using CSRFProtection http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html in my flask application.

Does every form generate a different CSRF token value (csrf_token)? It looks like the token value is not session based. It looks like different forms or when I refresh the page it will generate a new CSRF token. Is it the expected behavior? Thanks!!